# Grails app with CXF Plugin not generating WSDL

Tags: grails, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have a very simple Grails 3.1.4 app using the Cxf plugin (version 3.0.14). It has a service called MyService, which is annotated with @GrailsCxfEndpoint, and a method called doSomething() annotated with @WebMethod.

When I run the app and navigate to localhost:8080/myService?wsdl, I get an error page.  Same thing with localhost:8080?wsdl.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm completely stuck here. Any tips, pointers, or even, "You idiot, you forgot to...", would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the service is called `MyService`, then the default URL for the WSDL is

```
/services/my?wsdl
```